# Big Integer Arithmetic in Java - Homework

Tags: java, math, arbitrary-precision

So this is a homework assignment, and I've been working on it for about ~10 hours total. I'd just like some tips to see where I'm going wrong. So my assignment is to essentially make a calculator for big integers, and my professor provided the skeleton. The functions he asked us to write are to subtract, divide, multiply, exponentiation (x^n), and a lessthan function. I'm pretty sure my lessThan and multiply functions work correctly, but perhaps not, anyways, my work is below and I'll describe my problems afterwards:

```
public class Calc {

//
// main
//
// Parses the command-line arguments as an integer
// operation, packages the operands as digit arrays,
// calls the appropriate calculator function, and 
// then outputs the result.
//
public static void main(String[] args) {
if (args.length == 3) {
    int[] input1 = construct(args[0]);
    int[] input2 = construct(args[2]);
    if (args[1].equals("plus")) {
    int[] result = plus(input1,input2);
    putln(result);
    } else if (args[1].equals("minus")) {
    int[] result = minus(input1,input2);
    putln(result);
    } else if (args[1].equals("times")) {
    int[] result = times(input1,input2);
    putln(result);
    } else if (args[1].equals("div")) {
    int[] result = div(input1,input2);
    putln(result);
    } else if (args[1].equals("power")) {
    int[] result = power(input1,input2);
    putln(result);
    } else if (args[1].equals("less")) {
    boolean result = lessThan(input1,input2);
    TextIO.putln(result);
    } else if (args[1].equals("equal")) {
    boolean result = equal(input1,input2);
    TextIO.putln(result);
    } else {
    TextIO.putln("Invalid binary operation.  Try using +, -, +, /, ^, <, or =.");
    }
} else if (args.length == 2) {
    int[] input = construct(args[0]);
    // it must be a unary operation
    if (args[1].equals("!")) {
    int[] result = factorial(input);
    TextIO.putln(result);
    } else {
    TextIO.putln("Expected factorial operation!");
    }
} else {
    TextIO.putln("Invalid input.  Try either a binary operation or factorial.");
}
}


//
// plus
//
// Computes the sum of two digit arrays,
// represented as a digit array.
//
public static int[] plus(int[] a, int[] b) {

// Determine the result's maximum length.
//
int alen, blen, len;
alen = length(a);
blen = length(b);
if (alen > blen) {
    len = alen + 1;
} else {
    len = blen + 1;
}

// Allocate an array of digits with that length.
//
int[] c = new int[len];

// Compute the sum of the digits, working from
// least to most significant.
//
int carry = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i = i+1) {
    int sum = carry;
    if (i < alen) {
    sum = sum + a[i];
    }
    if (i < blen) {
    sum = sum + b[i];
    }
    c[i] = sum % 10;
    carry = sum / 10;
}

// Trim off the leading 0s.
//
return trim(c);
}

// INCOMPLETE
//
// minus
//
// Computes the difference of two digit arrays,
// represented as a digit array.
//
// You can assume that the first operand is 
// larger than the second one.
//
public static int[] minus(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if(equal(a,b))
    {
        int [] zero = new int [1];
                zero[0] = 0;
        return zero;
    }
    else{

    int c = 0;

    int lb = length(b);
    while(lb > c)
        {
            b[c] = (b[c]) * (-1);
            c++;
        }
    return plus(a,b);
    }
}


// INCOMPLETE
//
// times
//
// Computes the product of two digit arrays,
// represented as a digit array.
//
// HINT: use repeated addition.  You might need
//       to write lessThan first.
//
// BONUS: perform this using the schoolbook 
//        method.
//
public static int[] times(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int len;
        if(length(a) > length(b))
            len = length(a) + 1;
        else
            len = length(b) + 1;
        int[] c = new int[len];
        int[]counterArray;
        if(lessThan(a,b))
        {
            counterArray = new int[length(b)];
            counterArray[length(b)-1] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            counterArray = new int[length(a)];
            counterArray[length(a)-1] = 1;
        }

        int[] counterTwo = new int[1];
        counterTwo[0] = 1;
        while(lessThan(counterArray,a))
            {
        c = plus(c,b);
        counterArray = plus(counterArray, counterTwo);
            }
        return plus(c,b);
}

// INCOMPLETE
//
// div
//
// Computes the quotient of two digit arrays,
// represented as a digit array.
//
public static int[] div(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] counter = zero();
    boolean value = true;
    if(lessThan(a,b))
        return zero();
    else {
        while(value)
        {
            a = minus(a,b);
            counter = plus(counter,one());
            if(lessThan(b,a))
                value = false;

        }
        return counter;
    }

/**boolean checker = false;
int[] c = new int[length(a)];
for(int i = 0; i < length(a); i++)
{
    c[i] = 0;
}
int counter = 0;
while (!checker)
{
    if(equal(a,c))
    {
        checker = true;

    }
    else if(lessThan(a,c))
    {
        checker = true;
    }
    else if (lessThan(c,a))
    {
        c = plus(c,b);
        counter++;
    }
}
return construct("" + (counter));*/
}

// 
// factorial
//
// Computes the factorial of a digit array,
// as a digit array.
//
public static int[] factorial(int[] a) {
int[] count = one();
int[] product = one();
while (lessThan(count,a) || equal(count,a)) {
    product = times(product,count);
    count = plus(count,one());
}
return product;
}

// INCOMPLETE
// 
// power
//
// Computes the p-th power of a digit array x, 
// where p is also given as a digit array.  The
// result is calculated as a digit array.
//
public static int[] power(int[] x, int[] p) {
    int pl = length(p);
    int[] checker = new int[1];
    checker[0] = 0;
    int[] adder = new int[1];
    adder[0] = 0;
    if ((p[pl - 1] % 2) == 0)
        {
            while(equal(checker,p) == false)
            {
                adder = plus(square(x),adder);
                p = minus(p,construct("" + 2));
            }
            return adder;
        }
    else
    {
        int[] checkertwo = new int[1];
        checkertwo[0] = 1;
        while(equal(checkertwo,p) == false)
        {
            adder = plus(square(x), adder);
            p = minus(p,construct("" + 2));
        }
        return times(adder,x);
    }
}

public static int[] square(int[] x)
{
    return times(x,x);
}

//
// equal
//
// Returns whether or not two digit arrays 
// represent the same number.
//
public static boolean equal(int[] a, int[] b) {
int[] ta = trim(a);
int[] tb = trim(b);
if (ta.length != tb.length) {
    return false;
} else {
    for (int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i = i-1) {
    if (a[i] != b[i]) {
        return false;
    }
    }
    return true;
}
}

// INCOMPLETE
//
// lessThan
//
// Returns whether or not one digit array
// represents a number less than another.
//
public static boolean lessThan(int[] a, int[] b) {
boolean value = false;
a = minus(a,construct(""+0));
b = minus(b,construct(""+0));
if(length(b) > length(a))
{
    value = true;
}
else if(length(a) == length(b))
{
    boolean c = false;
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < length(a))
        {
        c = false;
            if(a[counter] > b[counter])
            {
                c = true;
                value = false;
            }
            if(!c)
                value = true;
            counter++;
        }
}
else
    value = false;
return value;

}

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
//
// These are helper functions that can be used in 
// the above code.
//

//
// construct
//
// Converts a string that consists of decimal digits
// into an array of those digits.
//
public static int[] construct(String digits) {
int len;
int[] a;

len = digits.length();
a = new int[len];

// Copy each digit of the string into
// the digit array, but as integers 
// rather than characters.

for (int i = len-1; i >= 0; i = i-1) {

    // get the i-th digit
    char c = digits.charAt(i);

    // check if it is a valid digit
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
    a[len-1-i] = (int)(c-'0');
    } else {
    // treat nondigits as 0 digits
    a[len-1-i] = 0;
    }
}

// trim off leading 0s
return trim(a);
}

//
// zero
//
// returns the digits representing 0
//
public static int[] zero() {
return construct("0");
}

//
// one
//
// returns the digits representing 0
//
public static int[] one() {
return construct("1");
}

//
// trim
//
// Takes an array of integer digits representing an integer,
// one that may have leading 0 digits, and constructs an 
// array with no leading digits.
//
public static int[] trim(int[] a) {
int len = length(a);

int[] b;
// build an array of that length
b = new int[len];

// set the digits
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    b[i] = a[i];
}

return b;
}

// 
// put
//
// Outputs an array of digits, from most- to least-
// significant, excluding any leading 0s.
//
public static void put(int[] a) {
int len = length(a);

for (int i = len-1; i >= 0; i = i-1) {
    TextIO.put(a[i]);
}
}

// 
// putln
//
// Outputs an array of digits, from most- to least-
// significant, excluding any leading 0s, followed by
// a carriage return.
//
public static void putln(int[] a) {
put(a);
TextIO.putln();
}

// 
// length
//
// Counts the number of digits in a digit array
// excluding leading 0s.
//
public static int length(int[] a) {
int len = a.length;

// figure out the number's real length
while (len > 0 && a[len-1] == 0) {
    len = len - 1;
}
if (len == 0) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return len;
}
}

}
```

My minus function seems to not work, for some reason, I don't know what's wrong. It makes sense to me that x - y = x + (-y) which is what I thought I correctly did. Perhaps the plus function my professor wrote doesn't work well with that? I've tried to think about it. And I think this minus function is integral to my divide and power functions. I'm sorry my notes aren't clear, but could someone please look it over and give me advice on where I'm fucking up with the minus function most importantly, because I think once I get that to work correctly I can do the rest.

Comment: Your static methods scare me.

Comment: Your thought that `x - y = x + (-y)` is of course correct, but your calculator only knows about positive integers, so you cannot put that idea to use.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not tested, but it should work:

```
public static int[] minus(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int len = length(a);
    int blen = length(b);

    int[] c = new int[len];

    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i = i+1) {

        int sum = a[i] - carry;
        if (i < blen) sum -= b[i];
        if (sum < 0) {
            sum += 10;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
        c[i] = sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense, I thought about doing something like that, but I was quite gungho about using the plus function. Thanks, it makes sense to me now. And now I've done all of them except power and times.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code towards the end of the `plus` method (within the *for* loop).

```
carry = sum / 10; // existing

if (c[i] < 0) {
   c[i] = c[i] + 10; // Create a positive complement of base 10.
   carry = carry - 1; // Borrowed. (or carry = -1)
}
```

Without this fix, when the second operand digit is bigger, it would return a negative value which would appear as -*digit* in the result. For example, `12 + (-8)` would be printed as `1-6`